# UWP GET my computer local bluetooth mac address

Tags: uwp, bluetooth

As subject.  I need get the local mac address of the computer and can't find an api.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothadapter.bluetoothaddress?view=winrt-19041

Comment: @MikePetrichenko the "BluetoothAdapter " is not the local device's BluetoothAdapter .

Comment: It is exactly the local Bluetooth adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP GET my computer local bluetooth mac address

I'm afraid you can't get bluetooth radio mac address with UWP api, for your requirement, we suggest you use win32 api to get it, in other words call win32 api in UWP desktop extension. And [32feet.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/32feet.NET/3.5.0) nuget could use to get bluetooth mac address.

**Code**

```
public static BluetoothAddress GetBTMacAddress()
{

    BluetoothRadio myRadio = BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio;
    if (myRadio == null)
    {
       
        return null;
    }

    return myRadio.LocalAddress;
}
```

[image]

I got it, BluetoothAddress getting from UWP api is decimal number. and above is hexadecimal number, they are same value. I use the following to convert to hexadecimal. thanks for @Mike Petrichenko's comment below.

```
 var adapter = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();
 var bleAddress = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(adapter.BluetoothAddress.ToString()), 16).ToUpper();
```

Comment: It is possible use class (BluetoothAdapter) I described above. And, of course, it can be done with Win API and with Bluetooth Framework as well (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm)

Comment: I have update the case reply thanks for the comments.

Comment: BluetoothAdapter.BluetoothAddress is already Int64 value (ulong) so it can be much simple: adapter.BluetoothAddress.ToString("X12") (MAC is 6 bytes long, 12 hexadecimal digits).